# How can I manage bandwidth consumption of GoToMeeting?

Tags: bandwidth, voip, qos, gotomeeting

GoToMeeting sessions hog all my networks bandwidth... I have business class cable and other video/audio apps (e.g. Skype, Google Hangouts or Webex) work properly.

In a session yesterday, I initially tried connecting via VoIP from a Windows 8.1 machine and the audio was very robotic. I stopped VoIP and dialed in from my VoIP phone and while GoToMeeting was still connected, my phone audio was very flakey.

As soon as I dropped GoToMeeting, my VoIP phone worked properly. I switched to Google Hangouts (with video) and everything was fine.

I have a DD-WRT router and QoS is *not* turned on.

Comment: If you reduce the bandwidth to GoToMeeting then the quality of your session will be worst.  If you have the bandwidth, then you should make sure all your hardware has 1000/100/10 ports, honestly this sounds like a service provider problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Logging into your router, and going to the QoS tab and Enabling the service.

Once enabled be sure your port is set to WAN, and under services begin to setup your rules. It sounds like your VoIP use is most important to you so I would first recommend limiting regular bandwidth from GoToMeeting and any other web application by either finding GoToMeeting in the drop down list under services or adding/editing services setting the three ports: 80, 443 and 8200 to a Standard priority.

I would then find out what port(s) your current VoIP provider uses and add a service for those ports and set them to Premium.  This will ensure the router gives priority to the VoIP traffic when needed.  Be sure to save and apply changes, which may require a reboot of the router.

If you would like to prioritize traffic by the IP address or by a MAC address I would recommend [this “How to Geek” article](http://www.howtogeek.com/70659/how-to-give-your-computers-network-traffic-priority-with-dd-wrt/).

Comment: This helps; however, VoIP is NOT always the priority... I just used this as an example of where GTM was bogging everything down... I use Google Hangouts all the time, and I wouldn't want this to take a back seat priority wise (e.g. I would not use GTM and Hangouts at same time)... Do we know what ports Hangouts use?

Comment: The preferred Google hangout ports are 19302 - 19309   (UDP), you will need to sure you port forward these ports to the IP address you use Google hangout from to ensure these ports are being used.  https://support.google.com/a/answer/1279090?hl=en.  If anything trying out the above answer shouldn't bog down anything, it will just give priority to whatever is specified as premium.

Comment: I use GTM from a specific computer, so I've set that computer up with QoS on my DD-WRT and set it to standard. I've also set up my VoIP phone to be premium. Lets see if this makes a difference. Thanks for the input.