# Prioritize GotoMeeting audio

Tags: tomato, qos, gotomeeting

I am trying to prioritize GotoMeeting audio so that VOIP quality remains high when I'm in meetings even if other computers on the network are consuming a lot of bandwidth. I have enabled the QOS feature in my Tomato firmware, but there is not a dropdown item specifically for GotoMeeting. Is there an IP block or other way of identifying the GotoMeeting traffic?

I found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/686901/how-can-i-manage-bandwidth-consumption-of-gotomeeting) but it doesn't give any details about identifying the traffic.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this document from Citrix](http://img.citrixonline.com/dtsimages/ad/pdf/OSDFirewallSpec.pdf):

> Integrated Voice over IP connections are configured to work outbound through UDP
>   port 8200. Integrated webcam video support is configured through UDP port 1853

So you can use these two ports to identify the GotoMeeting traffic by putting them in the "DST Port" field in the traffic identification interface. For example:

[image]

If those ports are not open on your network, then you'll need to use the IP blocks listed in the linked document, but this will need to be updated/maintained over time.